# How does "watch" work on concatenated commands?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, console, csh, watch

Something has been bugging me a while now:

```
watch cat file
```

works fine and reports output in the file every 2 secs.

```
watch cat file | grep "text"
```

does work, but its all weird in only one row.

What is the correct syntax for coupled commmands over watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes around the commands after watch:

```
watch 'cat file | grep "text"'
```